# Module '"./node_modules/react-native"' has no exported member 'View'

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

After i convert my project in typescript showing me following error
**Module '"./node_modules/react-native"' has no exported member 'View'.**

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet,View,Text} from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <Text>Welcome</Text>
  </View>
 );
}
```

Comment: remove the `nodemodules` folder and do `npm install` again

Answer (score 14):

1. Delete your `node_modules` folder
2. run this on your terminal `npm install @types/react @types/react-native`
3. close the editor and restart everything.

Answer (score 4):

Delete `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` or `yarn` again.

If it not solve this problem, try to run `npm install @types/react @types/react-native` or `yarn add @types/react @types/react-native`

Answer (score 2):

Probably you should also use -D option to install it as a development dependency, which adds it to the devDependencies list.

```
npm install --save-dev @types/react @types/react-native
(npm install -D @types/react @types/react-native)
```

or

```
yarn add --dev @types/react @types/react-native
(yarn add -D @types/react @types/react-native)
```